# Apache: proxypass docker container to subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, docker, apache2

The subdomain `sub.example.com` is hosted on AWS EC2, Amazon linux 2 OS based on centos. It runs php7 lampp stack. webroot is `/var/www/html`.

We don't have access to the domain, `example.com`, it's with the client on another server, he added our subdomain CNAME. The AWS server only hosts the subdomain.

Docker runs on `localhost:8080/cms`, it has php5 lampp stack, because the cms is built using cakephp 2 which only works with php5, the rest of our backend uses php7.

`docker run --name cakephp --always-restart -p 8080:80 -d -v /home/ec2-user/cms:/var/www/html porchn/php5.6-apache`

now, without any apache configuration whatsoever, clean lampp installation, if you go to

`localhost:8080/cms`  or `server-ip:8080/cms`

it redirects to

`sub.example.com:8080/cms`

That works, so it seems to me that the apache understands `sub.example.com` as the main domain and not as a subdomain

All I want to do is do a proxypass, so instead of one going to

`sub.example.com:8080/cms`

he should be able to go to

`sub.example.com/cms`

But that's not working, I tried many proxy configurations on the main server, I didn't touch the apache inside docker.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On 
 ProxyRequests Off
 ServerName www.sub.example.com
 ServerAlias sub.example.com
 ProxyPass / sub.example.com:8080/cms
 ProxyPassReverse / sub.example.com:8080/cms
 </VirtualHost>
```

1. `ProxyPass / sub.example.com:8080/cms` redirects to `example.com`, not `sub.example.com`, I don't want that because I don't have access to the main domain
2. I don't think I need to specify `servername`, because apache understands `sub.example.com` as the main domain, again I tried every combination before posting this question, nothing works, I'm not sure how the dns configuration is done either. I'd like to specify a `servername` though because that way certbot would be able to detect it and add letsencrypt to it
3. I don't know if I need to specify a `DocumentRoot` or not, again I tried every combination before coming here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one on Your outer apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On 
 ProxyRequests Off
 ServerName www.sub.example.com
 ServerAlias sub.example.com
 ProxyPass /cms/ http://sub.example.com:8080/cms/
 ProxyPassReverse /cms/ http://sub.example.com:8080/cms/
</VirtualHost>
```

first, if that not works post the redirect header of the request to http://sub.example.com/cms/.

Also keep in mind that sub.example.com might need to resolve to the external (elastic) IP whereas on the local server it needs to resolve to the loopback or local IP if You want use sub.example.com for proxy pass and sub.example.com is pointing to the public IP / is to be reachable from public internet.

If possibly I would recommend to use localhost - and explitly set Host-Header if ProxyPreserveHost must be on, just to not need to expose the port on address different to loopback.

And for Your Bullet-Points:

1. `ProxyPass / sub.example.com:8080/cms` redirects to `example.com`, not `sub.example.com` => ProxyPass does not redirect at all, it proxies/forwards. Possibly You got a redirect from Your app or webserver in container because the request to `http://sub.example.com/cms/` came to the containers apache as a request to `http://sub.example.com:8080/cmscms/` - or it did not hit the container at all (I'm not sure whether ProxyPass is valid without specifying a protocol)
2. Apache does not understand any domain as a main domain by itself if it is not configured somewhere or is resolver from hostname or such.. But this should not be a problem (but You may not want to include www.sub.example.com as server name if there is no CNAME that resolves to Your servers hostname/ip in addtion to the CNAME for sub.example.com, it shouldn't harm but could generate confusing outpout/links and maybe makes configuration difficult at some point as the main domain of that vhost is not a valid domain then)
3. Document root should not matter here. (It's always better to have a document root that is accessible/usable for apache as some things You do not expected to depend on accessible document may fail if it isn't).

Comment: Sorry I had wrong ProxyPassReverse statement (copied from Your blog but not adjust it to reflect the target setup). It's fixed now.